# Boost Date time conversion and adding seconds

Tags: c++, boost

I need to load in a string of format 16/11/2012  11:00:00 i.e %d/%m/%Y %H:%M and then repeatedly add 900 seconds to it. The code below is an example, could you help me get it working?

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "boost/date_time/local_time/local_date_time.hpp"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  unsigned int seconds=900;
  using namespace boost::local_time;
  std::stringstream ss;

  // Set up the input datetime format.
  local_time_input_facet *input_facet = new local_time_input_facet("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M");
  ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), input_facet));

  local_date_time date(not_a_date_time);
  ss.str("16/11/2012 11:00:00");
  ss >>date;

  local_date_time now=date+seconds;
  std::cout << now << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
James

Comment: Dangerous if you need precision and your architecture supports leap-seconds. Add minutes instead.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have boost in hands right now, please try something like:

`date + boost::posix_time::seconds(900)`

Comment: Ok, great, thanks. I think I'm still missing some headers; local_time_input_facet is undefined.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/date_time/time_input_facet.html

Comment: Hi, I included #include "boost/date_time/time_facet.hpp" but still having problems with local_time_input_facet